# Copying dateTime claims in B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In a B2C custom policy I'm storing a dateTime value in an extension attribute. I need to copy the value from this attribute into another attribute before updating the original when a user signs in. This is so we can display a 'You last signed into the application on: dd-mmm-yyyy.'

Therefore I need to store the date time of the user's previous sign in. The first step, I've done by storing the date time of the current sign in, but I need to copy this value into a second attribute before overwritting the original with this sign in's date time.

However when checking the list of available claims transformations in B2C custom policies, it does not appear it is possible to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/general-transformations, as the CopyClaim transformation only works with strings and ints. And the list of available transformations for Dates is limited.

The only possible way I could see of getting around this, would be to call a rest api, where I pass in the value from the original attribute, then return this exact same value as the output of the api and then store this value in the other attribute.

This seems massively over the top, to just copy a value from one attribute to another. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use different logic for this.

1. Create two attributes: [Date]`extension_currentLoginTime` & [Date]`extension_lastLoginTime`.
2. When user sign up, or first sign in, use `GenerateDateTime` claim transform and write the `currentTime` claim to `extension_currentLoginTime` and `extension_lastLoginTime`.
3. Return the `extension_lastLoginTime` into the token
4. When the user performs a sign in, read the `extension_currentLoginTime` and persist this to `extension_lastLoginTime`

   The following snippet shows how to **write** the content of one claim to any attribute.
   This means, you don't need to first copy the claim.

   ```xml
   <PersistedClaims>
     <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_currentLoginTime" PartnerClaimType="extension_lastLoginTime"/>
   </PersistedClaims>
   ```
5. Use `GenerateDateTime` claim transform and write the `currentTime` claim to `extension_currentLoginTime`.